# Can I run a VBA function whenever excel calculates, even when I don't click F9?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is a followup question to this one: [Can I make Excel beep when a calculation is finished?](https://superuser.com/questions/751350/can-i-make-excel-beep-when-a-calculation-is-finished)

The answer relies on me pressing F9.

However, even with calculations on manual, sometimes calculations happen without F9 - e.g. when I save the document.

Is there any event that I can use when a calculation happens regardless of what initiated it?

Comment: I think you would have to work this to each event (a guess). So, on the load/save/exit events and any other, you would probably need to wire up the function to fire on each event!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Worksheet event `Worksheet_Calculate` or the Workbook event `Workbook_SheetCalculate`
It's easy for those to start firing infinite loops, though, so be careful