# Is there a way to include "workbook" event functions in my personal macros file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

e.g.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Beep
End Sub
```

This only works in "ThisWorkbook," and only in 1 spreadsheet at a time, not in my personal.xlsb file.
(Inspired from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/850891/can-i-run-a-vba-function-whenever-excel-calculates-even-when-i-dont-click-f9?noredirect=1#comment1123588_850891).)

Comment: You can call a macro in your personal workbook from a different workbook, but I don't recommend it. You'd be the only person who'd ever be able to use the workbook unless you had a way to add the code to be called to personal.xls. Are you really just trying to make it beep, or is the actual code more complex than this?

Comment: @RubberDuck really just make it beep. I want to know when a (sometimes) long calculation is finished. This particular event function doesn't work from my personal workbook.

Comment: Don't bother. Any code you write to do this will be longer than just calling `Beep` directly from the `Workbook_AfterSave` event.

Comment: @RubberDuck But I only want it to beep for me, not for other users who open and save the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to display project properties.
2. Name the VBAProject for your personal workbook `Personal`
3. Create a subroutine that calls beep.

   ```
   Public Sub MakeItBeep
       Beep
   End Sub
   ```
4. In the workbook you want to enable this in, click on <kbd>Tools</kbd>>><kbd>References</kbd> on the menu bar.
5. Click <kbd>Browse...</kbd>
6. Find your Personal.xls file and select it. (It could be in a number of different locations, so searching the `C:\` drive is usually the easiest way to go about finding it.)
7. In the proper event of your workbook, insert this code (adjusting for module name of course).

   ```
   Personal.Module1.MakeItBeep
   ```

---

There are a couple of problems with this though, and I really don't recommend it.

1. This is much more code and work than just calling `Beep` directly.
2. This will most likely cause an error for any other user who works with the workbook. They would need to disable macros on this book. So, if there are any other macros that *need* to function, you can't do this.

You could use directives to work around that, but it's an awful lot of work for zero benefit. If you're still interested, I wrote a tutorial about [how to use conditional compilation with a project level setting](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/setting-up-a-debug-environment-for-vba/).

Comment: Very interesting! Though I have other macros in the workbook that I'd like other users to use as well...

Comment: Read the blog article I posted. You would need to conditionally compile the code then ***and*** remember to disable your beep code before sharing the workbook.